# How can I retrieve all the attribute names of an item in DynamoDB (only keys, no values)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to retrieve just the attribute names and ignore the attribute values of a single item in DynamoDB? I know I can use the `GetItem` call and discard the attribute values on the client, but my attribute values can be quite large.

My use case is that I have a potentially huge number of attributes names that match this format `foo-bar-YYYY-MM-DD`. The values that each attribute stores can be quite large too - around 100KB each. My goal is to have a script that deletes all attributes that are beyond a few weeks old (based on the `foo-bar-YYYY-MM-DD` attribute name).

Retrieving this huge amount of attribute value for each attribute name via the `getItem` call is unnecessary for me. It would be amazing if I can just fetch all the attribute keys of a single item without having to deal with excess memory concerns.

Comment: No there is not. You have to get the entire item.

Comment: You say you have a large number of attributes with values up to 100k each.  The max item size is 400kb, so you'd only have 4 attributes per item at most.  Do you mean you have a large number of items?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the response. I checked with AWS support as well and they told me the same. They did mention that they will make a ticket on Amazon side for this, but wonder if that will see the light of day considering my request is probably not too important :-)

Comment: @SethGeoghegan Currently I do not have any attribute value that is this huge yet, but in the future it might. I was under the impression that 400k limit is for each attribute name + attribute value pair. I thought the entire item itself can be very large without limits

Edit: Ok sadly I see that I am wrong :( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html
The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB, which includes both attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the size limit.

Comment: Why not stores these attributes as individual items?  Incorporating the time component in your primary key will let you fetch items within a certain date range and expire them to meet your use case.  Alternatively, you might consider enabling Time-To-Live on your table (TTL) and let DynamoDB worry about deleting expired items.

It sounds like you're using an unconventional approach to a common problem.

Comment: Makes sense. The reason I went for this approach was because these attributes are always accessed via my existing item's primary key. I think I was stuck in the mindset to keep everything in one table and all related data within a single item. But pulling them out into their own item (and maybe its own table?) works much better I think. Thank you for taking the time and your thoughts!